# Was bedeutet binden?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary, swiss-german

Ich habe gerade den 3. Aufzug von Friedrich Schillers Drama "Wilhelm Tell" gelesen. In Vers 2068 wird Tell *gebunden*. Was bedeutet dies (und warum)?

Quelle: https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Tell/Dritter_Aufzug (bei/nach [149])

Comment: Bitte erkläre, warum ein Blick ins Wörterbuch nicht geholfen hat. Was ist der Kontext? Welche Bedeutungen kommen infrage?

Comment: Ebenso hülfe die Lektüre von ein oder zwei Karl-May-Romanen. Auch dort werden Leute fortwährend gebunden, meistens Bösewichter, wenn der Held sie endlich erwischt hat, manchmal aber auch Gutewichter, die der Held dann unter behendem Anschleichen befreit.

Comment: @CarstenS Habe ich gemacht, allerdings stand dort keine passende Bedeutung. "Binden" ist irgendeine Art von Strafe.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich bin mir nicht sicher, aber ich glaube nicht das dies im Kontext passt.

Comment: @ErnestBredar, genau aus diesem Grund wäre mehr Kontext, wie zum Beispiel die betreffende Textstelle, hilfreich.

Comment: Da vielleicht nicht jeder den Tell griffbereit hat und sich dann auch nicht unbedingt die Mühe des Raussuchens machen möchte: Ja, es wäre gut, die entsprechende Textpassage direkt in die Frage zu schreiben. (Üblicherweise mit einem > vorne dran, zur Markierung.)

Comment: @ErnestBredar  Dein Kommentar oben steht etwas verloren herum. Ich vermute, er bezieht sich auf einen früheren von mir, in dem ich riet, *binden* als *fesseln* zu verstehen, weil *jemanden binden* das ganze 19. Jahrhundert über ein gebräuchlicher Ausdruck für *jemanden fesseln* war. Warum der Kommentar jetzt weg ist, verstehe ich nicht recht, aber so ist es halt. - Karl May verwendet *jemanden binden* in praktisch jedem seiner Reiseromane in nämlicher Weise.

Answer (score 3):

Die Stelle lautet im Kontext:

> **Geßler** (zeigt auf den Knaben):
>
> Man bind ihn an die Linde dort!
>
> **Walther Tell**
>
> Mich binden!
>
> Nein, ich will nicht gebunden seyn. Ich will
>
> Still halten, wie ein Lamm und auch nicht athmen.
>
> Wenn ihr mich bindet, nein, so kann ichs nicht,
>
> So werd’ ich toben gegen meine Bande.

weiter unten heißt es:

> **Geßler**
>
> Wohl, Tell! Des Lebens hab ich dich gesichert,
>
> Ich gab mein Ritterwort, das will ich halten –
>
> Doch weil ich deinen bösen Sinn erkannt,
>
> Will ich dich führen lassen und verwahren,
>
> Wo weder Mond noch Sonne dich bescheint,
>
> Damit ich sicher sei vor deinen Pfeilen.
>
> Ergreift ihn, Knechte! Bindet ihn!
>
> (Tell wird gebunden)

An allen Stellen hat das Verb *binden* die Bedeutung *fesseln*. *Bande* heißt hier *Fessel*, *Fesselung*.

Comment: Du hast nicht weit genug nach unten gescrollt. Links von dem von dir kopierten Text steht "[140]". Ich meinte aber zwischen [149] und [150].

Comment: @ErnestBredar OK. Aber auch dort hat _binden_ die gleiche Bedeutung.

Comment: Und warum ist das dann ein Problem (das gebunden sein, meine ich)?

Comment: Ein Hauptthema in _Wilhelm Tell_ ist die Freiheit. Gebunden sein ist für Wilhelm Tell ein unerträglicher Zustand. Auch die Replik von Walther geht in die gleiche Richtung.

Comment: Ich meine damit: Warum wird er nicht gleich wieder befreit. Genug Leute sind ja da.

Comment: @ErnestBredar Da musst du Herrn Schiller fragen. Es ist jedenfalls keine Frage zur Deutschen Sprache mehr :-)

Comment: Und wie bringe ich das jetzt der Software bei?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94175/discussion-between-jonathan-scholbach-and-ernest-bredar).